# Is it true that any enumerable set of real numbers can be put in monotone order?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was thinking: if we have any countable infinite set of real numbers (because it is a set it must have infinite different values) let's say for example:

$X = \{\frac1n , \forall n \geq 1, n \in \mathbb N\}$

can we build a sequence $a_n$ only with the elements of this set (and that covers the whole set), such that $a_n$ is monotone?

My first tought was yes, but them I remembered that the rational numbers fit in this definition. And I can't really answer this question.

Comment: It seems to me that there is plenty of strictly monotone sequences $a_\bullet:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$. For instance $a_n=n$.

Comment: My guess is that you meant to write “a countable infinite set of real numbers” instead of “a set of countable infinite real numbers”.

Comment: It took your comments and edited the question, thank you both!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The questions in the title and in the message are not equivalent. You clearly can build a monotone sequence $a_n$ of **only** rational numbers.

When it comes to **only and all** rational numbers, you can't do that for at least two reasons. First of all, the set is unbounded from below, so you can't have $a_0$. Second of all, it is dense, meaning that between any $p,q$ there is $r: p<r<q$. So even if were able to find $a_0$, there's no immediate succesor, meaning that you aren't able to find $a_1$.

So creating a monotone sequence of **only and all** numbers of a set $X \subseteq \mathbb R$ is only possible when $X$ has a minimum, and when every of its elements is isolated -- ie. if for every $x \in X$ there is $\varepsilon >0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon) \cap X = \{x\}$.

Comment: is there a proof for your statement? "If X is bounded and it's elements are isolated we can order it."

Comment: I'm a bit out of shape, but let's try.

Well, first of all you have to see that a set with isolated elements is closed. So if it has an infimum, it has a minimum.

So our set has a minimum, $a_0$. The set $X\setminus \{a_0\}$ retains the property of isolated elements, so it too has a minimu, $a_1$. Then consider the set $X \setminus \{a_0,a_1\}$ and so on.

Comment: @MichałZapała This does define a monotone sequence in $X$ starting from its smallest value but one must still show that all elements of $X$ are reached. A priori, $X$ could have order type $\omega + 1$, whence this procedure has image $\omega$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Real numbers ar Archimedean, so no set with order type greater than $\omega$ can be isolated. Of course that's something I neglected in my message.

Comment: At first glance your statement solves the question for me. I don't think the set $X = \mathbb Z$ can be put in a monotone sequence because it is unbounded. I'll assume the statement is a "iff" with your restrictions: bounded and isolated.

Comment: it is interesting that in this case $a_n$ is bounded and monotone, so it must converge. Wait. It is looking weird, $X$ can be unlimited in some cases.

Comment: No, $a_n$ doesn't need to converge, as $X$ is only bounded from below.

Comment: yes but we could take $a_n = -n$ for example. I do think you got a lot cases tho

Comment: Oh, right, I took "monotone" to mean "increasing" when it could be "decreasing" just as well.

Comment: Well consider the set consisting of all elements of the form $1/n$ and $2-1/n$. This is bounded and each element is isolated and yet there is no min or max.

Comment: A set with isolated elements is not necessarily closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence you mentioned is already monotone (decreasing).  If you mean a arbitrary set (countable) to be ordered the answer is yes.